# I saw this plant in New York City

Tags: identification

[image]

I saw this plant around New York City. I don't think I've seen it before. I'm hoping to find it's name.

Comment: Welcome Sandy DeLeon! Thanks for adding us to your other network sites! This is a pretty plant! We have [guidelines](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) for posting identification questions. Details are important because identification can be tricky. Also, the title should describe the plant, so people who read it will have an idea of what's in the question. Editing according to the guidelines would help present and future visitors. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Amaranthus 'Early Splendour'.

Here's a photo to help confirm: [Amaranthus 'Early Splendour'](https://img1.etsystatic.com/045/0/9817393/il_570xN.738508257_oefs.jpg)

This is an annual cultivar - here's some more info: [Cultural Information](https://myfolia.com/plants/1304-amaranth-amaranthus/varieties/20522-early-splendor)

Comment: Thanks. I have some research to do. I might want to plant a few of these